# Error scraping website data using BS4

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv, python-unicode

I am using this piece of code to extract the data from a site.

```
url = 'https://www.dailythanthi.com/News/Puducherry/2018/06/09020308/Puducherry-budget-will-soon-get-approval--Narayanasamy.vpf'
details = requests.get(url, headers=url_headers )
encoding = details.encoding if 'charset' in details.headers.get('content-type', '').lower() else None
details_data = BeautifulSoup(details.content, "lxml", from_encoding=encoding)
# Remove all script tags
[s.extract() for s in details_data('script')]
details_div = details_data.find("div", {"id": "ArticleDetailContent"})
details_image = details_image_src.img['src']
details_text = []
paras = details_div.find_all("p")
for para in paras:
    details_text.append(para.get_text())

details_text = ''.join(details_text)
```

And writing them to a file using

```
with open("thanthi.csv", "w") as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerow(["Description"])
    writer.writerows([details_text])
```

## And this up with error saying

```
       writer.writerows(articles)
            UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-

4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am not sure this why this fails. Even I have tried to unicode them using the .encode('utf8') method the details and the error still occurs

Comment: it works "fine" if i change the last line to `writer.writerows([details_text.encode('utf-8')])`

Comment: Looks like working. Checking with few other urls. Can you add this as answer

Comment: Looks like some issue. Some times this causes some junk. eg.  ®à®°à¯ à®¨à®¾à®°à®¾à®¯à®£à®à®¾à®®à®¿ à®¨à¯à®±à¯à®±à¯ à®¨à®¿à®°à¯à®ªà®°à¯à®à®³à¯à®à¯à®à¯ à®ªà¯à®à¯à®à®¿ à®à®³à®¿à®¤à¯à®¤à®¾à®°à¯. à®à®ªà¯à®ªà¯à®¤à¯ à®à®µà®°à¯ à®à¯à®±à®¿à®¯à®¤à®¾à®µà®¤à¯:âà®ªà¯à®¤à¯à®µà¯à®¯à®¿à®©à¯ 2018â19à®®à¯ à®à®£à¯à®à¯à®à¯à®à®¾à®© à®ªà®à¯à®à¯à®à¯ à®à¯à®ªà¯à®ªà¯ à®®à®¤à¯à®¤à®¿à®¯ à®à®°à®à¯ à®à®©à¯à®ªà¯à®ªà®¿ . And this is the url https://www.dailythanthi.com/News/Puducherry/2018/06/10015330/The-Central-Government-should-cancel-the-NEET-Exam.vpf

Comment: that's why i used the scare quotes for "fine". i don't think csv is the most suited file type for your needs. it looks like it doesn't know how to split the data and thus randomly split the chars. sorry i can't help you

Comment: Please add the answer. I will fix this junk issue in another question.

Comment: my answer wasn't good at all. sorry. and thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172840/discussion-between-techonthenet-and-bobrobbob).